# What happens if both OTF and TTF version of the same font are installed?

Tags: windows, fonts

Windows (7) allows for simultaneous installation of the same font in different formats.

`cmd` shows that both .otf and .ttf files are present in `C:\Windows\Fonts`, but are they ever used? Or does the system always prefer one of the formats? Is this something that applications have control of?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, but all the advice I've seen so far recommends not to mix multiple formats of the same font to prevent conflicts. Couldn't find more details, so no idea if these conflicts were due to some program misbehaving, or Windows itself, and if the latter, whether it's been fixed in recent versions of the OS. If you have to choose one then OTF is supposed to be better I guess.

Comment: @Karan Anti-Aliasing is better with TTF though...

Comment: Could very well be the case, never bothered enough to compare. http://superuser.com/questions/96390 might be useful in case anyone's interested.

Comment: Not sure, but it may depend on the particural font.

Answer (score 0):

When using MS Publisher, I've noticed that TTF renders perfectly in WordArt but OTF renders pixelated and blotchy.  The downfall to using TTF though is that many "extras" such as special characters and swashes are only available in OTF versions.